# Image SRC Not Considered A Link Or Not Loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, src

I am building a small social media site to enhance my skills in HTML CSS & JS, but I have ran into a problem.

I have an `<img>` in a `<button>`, and I am trying to change that image `onclick()` [the button will hide some text under the button].

The problem is that the image will not load. When I click the button, the new image will not load, and when I re-click the image to reload the image that was in the fist place, it won't load either.

The only clue I have is this error massage every time I click the buttton `GET file:///C:/Users/emile/Desktop/Mini%20learning%20projects/Social%20App/scripts/iconsarrow-up.webp net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. This last part `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is weird because I copied the path of the image.

And when I try to open the image from the console in a new tab, it will tell me `Your file couldn’t be accessedIt may have been moved, edited, or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Any ideas ?

Here is the code:

```js
function ButtonHide() {
    const element = document.getElementById('friend-request-container'); 
    const personnaInfoDiv = document.getElementById('personnal-info');
    const sideBarArrowTooltip = document.getElementById('sidebup-arrow-tooltip');
    const friendRequestCount = document.getElementById('friend-request-count');
    const sidebarArrowImage = document.getElementById('friends-arrow');

    if (element.style.display === 'none') {
        element.style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById("personnal-info").style.marginBottom = "0px";
        sideBarArrowTooltip.innerHTML = 'Hide Requests';
        sidebarArrowImage.src = 'icons\arrow-up.webp';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
        friendRequestCount.style = 'display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 200px;';
        document.getElementById("personnal-info").style.marginBottom = "15px";
        sideBarArrowTooltip .innerHTML = 'Show Requests';
        sidebarArrowImage.src = 'icons\vector-down-arrow.png';
    }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 55px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 372px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

.sidebar-top-container {
    border-bottom: solid 2px rgb(199, 199, 199);;
}

.home {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px; 
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
}

.create-button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: rgb(23, 93, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 223px;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.personnal-info,
.friend-request-container {
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar-profile-picture {
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.my-user-name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    margin-left: 2px; 
}

.up-arrow {
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.friend-request-container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.friend-request-image {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 23px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}

.friend-request-count {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

.sidebar-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 190px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.name-and-profile {
    position: relative;
}

.up-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: -26px;
}

.name-and-profile {
    position: relative;
}

.hide-requests-button{
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 85px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 308px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 26.5px;
}

.hide-requests-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
}

.hide-requests-button:active {
    background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
}

.friend-request-count {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    color: rgb(118, 118, 118);
}

.sidebar-container .tooltip {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.sidebar-container .tooltip {
  z-index: 200;
}

.sidebar-container:hover .tooltip{
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar-container .tooltip {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  bottom: -30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.15s;
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-top-container">
                <div class="sidebar-heading">
                    <h1 class="home">Home</h1> 
                    <a class="create-button" href="C:\Users\emile\Desktop\Mini learning projects\Social App\scripts\Home Page.html">Create</a>
                </div>
                <div class="personnal-info" style="height: 32px;" id="personnal-info">
                    <div class="name-and-profile">
                        <img class="sidebar-profile-picture" src="C:\Users\emile\Desktop\New HTML Course\icons\my profile.jpg">
                        <p class="my-user-name">Emile Feghali</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sidebar-container">
                        <button class="hide-requests-button" onclick="ButtonHide()">
                            <img class="up-arrow" id="friends-arrow" src="C:\Users\emile\Desktop\New HTML Course\icons\arrow-up.webp">
                        </button>
                        <div class="tooltip" id="sidebup-arrow-tooltip">Hide Requests</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-request-container" id="friend-request-container">
                    <img class="friend-request-image" src="C:\Users\emile\Desktop\New HTML Course\icons\add-friends-image.jpg">
                    <p class="friend-request-count" id="friend-request-count">2 pending friend requests</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you should not apply your changes in JS with `.style`but with `classList.toggle` which going to save your entire if/else block. Beyond that, a `ternary conditional operator` would have been cleaner.

Comment: ok thanks, but do what is an `ternary conditional operator` and what does `classList.toggle` do other than make my if/else statements clearer, does it have any more uses I should know of ? Thanks !

Comment: a ternary conditional operator uses a true false statemens and declares a value for true or false such as: `element.style.display = (element.style.display === 'none') ? 'inline-block' : 'none';`.  `classList.toggle('class-name')` will add a class to an element if it does nto have the class and remove it if it has it. So you can make the changes at CSS level by toggling the class add/remove.

Comment: oh, thanks !  BTW any idea about my other problem ?

Comment: what does the console log says about it (F12)? You have to click on the link in the dev tools and check where it actually leads you too

Comment: In the image loaded in HTML, the image appears, but as soon as I click the button, the image changes into the thing that appears when there is no image or the image path was wrongly copied. I tried downloading several images and they all didn't work.

Comment: onclick, the console said `/C:/UsersemileDesktopMini%20learning%20projectsiconsdown-arrow.jpg:1          GET file:///C:/UsersemileDesktopMini%20learning%20projectsiconsdown-arrow.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: Change all the absolute paths in `href` and `src` to relative paths, relative to your html of course.

Comment: I changed the folder and moved all my photos in there, and then I copied relative path, but it didn't work.